# Обобщенный метод необобщенного класса

Tags: java, generics

В обобщенном классе параметр типа реализует возможность формирования обобщенных методов относительно этого параметра типа. Возможно ли формирование обобщенного метода в необобщенном классе?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, возможно.

```
public class Main {

    public static <T> void add(ArrayList<T> arrayList, T value) {
        arrayList.add(value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        stringArrayList.add("First");
    }
}
```

Параметризация каким-либо типом класса дает возможность использовать этот тип для полей класса. В методах же можно использовать обобщения внезависимости от того, обобщен класс или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Да. Вы можете сделать generic метод в любом классе.

```
public <T> T getFirst(List<T> list) {
    return list.get(0);
}
```